# Android: sliding views upwards with finger

Tags: android

I have a `View` defined in an XML, what I want is to let the user slide the view up and return if it doesn't go up half of the bar. But I don't find any links that help on Google search after some time of Googling. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: anyone? I still can't figure out how to fix such issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For moving a view with finger you can use the following idea: detect touches when user moves his finger and move the view according to the shift.

```
GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, 
  new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent event, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        view.setTranslationY(event.getY()-start.getY());
        return true;
    }
});

view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);  // here we pass events to detector above
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you want to return the view to initial position when user stops sliding, in `onTouch` (see above) write this:

```
if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    view.setTranslationY(0);
}
```

Comment: Please check if `onTouch` is called. If it is called only once, replace `return false` with `return true` inside it

Comment: `onTouch` is called every time when I touch the view

Comment: In `onTouch` you pass events to `gestureDetector` and so it is called. Please tell me whether `onTouch` is called only when you touch the view (put the finger on view) or also when you are moving finger over the view.